# Finding count of distinct elements in DataFrame in each column

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I am trying to find the count of distinct values in each column using Pandas. This is what I did.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Generate data.
NROW = 10000
NCOL = 100
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 100000, (NROW, NCOL)),
                  columns=['col' + x for x in np.arange(NCOL).astype(str)])
```

I need to count the number of distinct elements for each column, like this:

```
col0    9538
col1    9505
col2    9524
```

What would be the most efficient way to do this, as this method will be applied to files which have size greater than 1.5GB?

---

Based upon the answers, `df.apply(lambda x: len(x.unique()))` is the fastest ([notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1xsrG3iUR5fkouRtBTWA2oO8YJWYqNk4G)).

`%timeit df.apply(lambda x: len(x.unique()))
10 loops, best of 3: 49.5 ms per loop
%timeit df.nunique()
10 loops, best of 3: 59.7 ms per loop
%timeit df.apply(pd.Series.nunique)
10 loops, best of 3: 60.3 ms per loop
%timeit df.T.apply(lambda x: x.nunique(), axis=1)
10 loops, best of 3: 60.5 ms per loop`

Answer (score 97, accepted):

As of **pandas 0.20** we can use `nunique` directly on `DataFrame`s, i.e.:

```
df.nunique()
a    4
b    5
c    1
dtype: int64
```

***Other legacy options:***

You could do a transpose of the df and then using [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas.DataFrame.apply) call [`nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nunique.html#pandas.Series.nunique) row-wise:

```
In [205]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,1,1,2,3],'b':[1,2,3,4,5],'c':[1,1,1,1,1]})
df

Out[205]:
   a  b  c
0  0  1  1
1  1  2  1
2  1  3  1
3  2  4  1
4  3  5  1

In [206]:
df.T.apply(lambda x: x.nunique(), axis=1)

Out[206]:
a    4
b    5
c    1
dtype: int64
```

**EDIT**

As pointed out by @ajcr the transpose is unnecessary:

```
In [208]:
df.apply(pd.Series.nunique)

Out[208]:
a    4
b    5
c    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks! I just want to clarify, so what is happening is that for every column in df gets passed into apply one at a time where it uses pd.Series.nunique to get unique count? So basically for each column it runs .nunique() function?

Answer (score 8):

A `Pandas.Series` has a `.value_counts()` function that provides exactly what you want to. [Check out the documentation for the function](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html?highlight=value_count).

Comment: Can you demonstrate how this would look as you've posted no code and output

Comment: @EdChum -  df.value_counts(dropna = False).sort_index() will work.

Comment: >AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'value_counts'

Comment: Only works on a Series, so you should subset the dataframe to one column.

Answer (score 6):

Already some great answers here :) but this one seems to be missing:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.nunique())
```

As of pandas 0.20.0, `DataFrame.nunique()` is also available.

Answer (score 2):

I found:

```
df.agg(['nunique']).T
```

much faster

Answer (score 1):

Recently, I have same issues of counting unique value of each column in DataFrame, and I found some other function that runs faster than the `apply` function:

```
#Select the way how you want to store the output, could be pd.DataFrame or Dict, I will use Dict to demonstrate:
col_uni_val={}
for i in df.columns:
    col_uni_val[i] = len(df[i].unique())

#Import pprint to display dic nicely:
import pprint
pprint.pprint(col_uni_val)
```

This works for me almost twice faster than `df.apply(lambda x: len(x.unique()))`

Answer (score 0):

```
df.apply(lambda x: len(x.unique()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to segregate only the columns with more than 20 unique values for all the columns in pandas_python:

```
enter code here
col_with_morethan_20_unique_values_cat=[]
for col in data.columns:
    if data[col].dtype =='O':
        if len(data[col].unique()) >20:

        ....col_with_morethan_20_unique_values_cat.append(data[col].name)
        else:
            continue

print(col_with_morethan_20_unique_values_cat)
print('total number of columns with more than 20 number of unique value is',len(col_with_morethan_20_unique_values_cat))



 # The o/p will be as:
['CONTRACT NO', 'X2','X3',,,,,,,..]
total number of columns with more than 20 number of unique value is 25
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the example code for the answer given by @CaMaDuPe85

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,1,1,2,3],'b':[1,2,3,4,5],'c':[1,1,1,1,1]})
df

# df
    a   b   c
0   0   1   1
1   1   2   1
2   1   3   1
3   2   4   1
4   3   5   1


for cs in df.columns:
    print(cs,df[cs].value_counts().count()) 
    # using value_counts in each column and count it 

# Output

a 4
b 5
c 1
```