# efficient count distinct across columns of DataFrame, grouped by rows

Tags: python, performance, pandas, numpy, distinct-values

What is the fastest way (within the limits of sane pythonicity) to count distinct values, across columns of the same `dtype`, for each row in a `DataFrame`?

**Details:** I have a `DataFrame` of categorical outcomes by subject (in rows) by day (in columns), similar to something generated by the following.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def genSampleData(custCount, dayCount, discreteChoices):
    """generate example dataset"""
    np.random.seed(123)     
    return pd.concat([
               pd.DataFrame({'custId':np.array(range(1,int(custCount)+1))}),
               pd.DataFrame(
                columns = np.array(['day%d' % x for x in range(1,int(dayCount)+1)]),
                data = np.random.choice(a=np.array(discreteChoices), 
                                        size=(int(custCount), int(dayCount)))    
               )], axis=1)
```

For example, if the dataset tells us which drink each customer ordered on each visit to a store, I would like to know the count of distinct drinks per customer.

```
# notional discrete choice outcome          
drinkOptions, drinkIndex = np.unique(['coffee','tea','juice','soda','water'], 
                                     return_inverse=True) 

# integer-coded discrete choice outcomes
d = genSampleData(2,3, drinkIndex)
d
#   custId  day1  day2  day3
#0       1     1     4     1
#1       2     3     2     1

# Count distinct choices per subject -- this is what I want to do efficiently on larger DF
d.iloc[:,1:].apply(lambda x: len(np.unique(x)), axis=1)
#0    2
#1    3

# Note: I have coded the choices as `int` rather than `str` to speed up comparisons.
# To reconstruct the choice names, we could do:
# d.iloc[:,1:] = drinkOptions[d.iloc[:,1:]]
```

**What I have tried:** The datasets in this use case will have many more subjects than days (example `testDf` below), so I have tried to find the most efficient row-wise operation:

```
testDf = genSampleData(100000,3, drinkIndex)

#---- Original attempts ----
%timeit -n20 testDf.iloc[:,1:].apply(lambda x: x.nunique(), axis=1)
# I didn't wait for this to finish -- something more than 5 seconds per loop
%timeit -n20 testDf.iloc[:,1:].apply(lambda x: len(x.unique()), axis=1)
# Also too slow
%timeit -n20 testDf.iloc[:,1:].apply(lambda x: len(np.unique(x)), axis=1)
#20 loops, best of 3: 2.07 s per loop
```

To improve on my original attempt, we note that [pandas.DataFrame.apply()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) accepts the argument:

> If `raw=True` the passed function will receive ndarray objects instead.
>   If you are just applying a NumPy reduction function this will achieve
>   much better performance

This did cut the runtime by more than half:

```
%timeit -n20 testDf.iloc[:,1:].apply(lambda x: len(np.unique(x)), axis=1, raw=True)
#20 loops, best of 3: 721 ms per loop *best so far*
```

I was surprised that a pure numpy solution, which would seem to be equivalent to the above with `raw=True`, was actually a bit slower:

```
%timeit -n20 np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: len(np.unique(x)), axis=1, arr = testDf.iloc[:,1:].values)
#20 loops, best of 3: 1.04 s per loop
```

Finally, I also tried transposing the data in order to do [column-wise count distinct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30503321/finding-count-of-distinct-elements-in-dataframe-in-each-column), which I thought might be more efficient (at least for `DataFrame.apply()`, but there didn't seem to be a meaningful difference.

```
%timeit -n20 testDf.iloc[:,1:].T.apply(lambda x: len(np.unique(x)), raw=True)
#20 loops, best of 3: 712 ms per loop *best so far*
%timeit -n20 np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: len(np.unique(x)), axis=0, arr = testDf.iloc[:,1:].values.T)
# 20 loops, best of 3: 1.13 s per loop
```

So far my best solution is a strange mix of `df.apply` of `len(np.unique())`, but what else should I try?

Comment: Is the day count representative? It seems to affect the differences in performances greatly.

Comment: @ayhan interesting... the day count is representative for my particular use case but if something else works better for wider datasets that would be worth noting for other users

Comment: The opposite actually. It seems that comparing each column against the others is much faster when you have a small number of columns. I posted the results as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding is that nunique is optimized for large series. Here, you have only 3 days. Comparing each column against the others seems to be faster:

```
testDf = genSampleData(100000,3, drinkIndex)
days = testDf.columns[1:]

%timeit testDf.iloc[:, 1:].stack().groupby(level=0).nunique()
10 loops, best of 3: 46.8 ms per loop

%timeit pd.melt(testDf, id_vars ='custId').groupby('custId').value.nunique()
10 loops, best of 3: 47.6 ms per loop

%%timeit
testDf['nunique'] = 1
for col1, col2 in zip(days, days[1:]):
    testDf['nunique'] += ~((testDf[[col2]].values == testDf.ix[:, 'day1':col1].values)).any(axis=1)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.83 ms per loop
```

It loses its edge when you add more columns of course. For different number of columns (the same order: `stack().groupby()`, `pd.melt().groupby()` and loops):

```
10 columns: 143ms, 161ms, 30.9ms
50 columns: 749ms, 968ms, 635ms
100 columns: 1.52s, 2.11s, 2.33s
```

Comment: Yes, since that loop runs only a few times. I added the timings for higher number of columns too.

Comment: great answer!  +1, I'm still spinning my wheels insisting on a better solution.

Comment: @piRSquared I also feel like I can get rid of the loop with some kind of broadcasting but I'm note sure about the memory. But it definitely seems like a job that should take less time to complete.

Comment: This solution counts `nan` values as distinct, since `np.nan==np.nan` is `False`.  If we did not want to count `nan`, i.e., to count distinct non-missing values, we could tack on a `- np.sum(np.isnan(df),axis=1)` to the returned value.

Answer (score 2):

`pandas.melt` with `DataFrame.groupby` and `groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique` seems to blow the other solutions away:

```
%timeit -n20 pd.melt(testDf, id_vars ='custId').groupby('custId').value.nunique()
#20 loops, best of 3: 67.3 ms per loop
```

Comment: Maybe a caveat here that this is grouping by a column value rather than the row number.  If you didn't have a unique row id variable, you might want to factor in the (small) cost of creating one for a fair benchmark.

Comment: In all your other solutions, the `apply` loop was happening in python - here `Groupby.nunique` uses some tricks (see [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/groupby.py#L2896)) to do it all with vectorized operations.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `custId`.  I'd `stack`, then `groupby`

```
testDf.iloc[:, 1:].stack().groupby(level=0).nunique()
```

[image]