# How to get column-wise occurence of unique values

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to find the solution for following problem. My search bring no usable result.

I have following data frame:

```
d <- data.frame(v1 = c(0,1,1,0,0,1,1), 
                v2 = c(0,-1,1,1,-1,-1,-1), 
                v3 = c(1,1,1,1,0,1,1),
                v4 = c(-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1))
```

I would like to get column-wise occurence of unique values as follows:

```
  v1 v2 v3 v4
 1 4  2  6  0
 0 3  1  1  0
-1 0  4  0  7
```

How could I achieve this?

Thx for your support.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding count of distinct elements in DataFrame in each column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30503321/finding-count-of-distinct-elements-in-dataframe-in-each-column)

Answer (score 2):

You can just try `stack` and `table`:

```
table(stack(d))
##       ind
## values v1 v2 v3 v4
##     -1  0  4  0  7
##     0   3  1  1  0
##     1   4  2  6  0
```

There's also `mtabulate` from "qdapTools":

```
library(qdapTools)
mtabulate(d)
##    -1 0 1
## v1  0 3 4
## v2  4 1 2
## v3  0 1 6
## v4  7 0 0
```

You'll just need to `t`ranspose the result.

Comment: Great! Exactly what I was looking for. Thx a lot!